# UIColor Category Linker Errors

Tags: ios, unit-testing, linker-errors, uicolor

Earlier today I tried to add Unit tests to my xcode project for a static framework that I am creating. After adding the Unit Tests target to my project, I was able to successfully run the unit tests template and have the tests catch the default assertion. Then, after importing the file that I wanted to test into my new SenTestCase subclass, I tried to run the test but my UIColor category failed building with the test due to linker errors. The text of the linker errors is as follows:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGColorGetComponents", referenced from:
      -[UIColor(ColorExtension) hexValue] in StaticFramework(StaticFramework)
  "_CGColorGetNumberOfComponents", referenced from:
      -[UIColor(ColorExtension) hexValue] in StaticFramework(StaticFramework)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Next, I found where these two references were in my project. Both live in my category under the following function:

```
- (NSString *)hexValue
{
    UIColor *color = self;
    const size_t totalComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(color.CGColor);
    const CGFloat * components = CGColorGetComponents(color.CGColor);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#%02X%02X%02X",
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(0,totalComponents-2)]),
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(1,totalComponents-2)]),
            (int)(255 * components[MIN(2,totalComponents-2)])];
}
```

If I remember correctly, both of these are part of the NSColor class. With a little more inspection, I also noticed that in my Unit Test's framework's folder, both UIKit.framework & Foundation.framework are red. I have tried reimporting them and building but this does not fix that issue either.

Interestingly enough, my static framework will still build and run fine as long as the associated Test is not also run. And when I comment this function out (and every time I use it), the Unit Test builds without issues. Would I be correct in my assumption that the missing UIKit.framework & Foundation.framework could be causing the linker not finding the NSColor properties? Does anyone have any additional suggestions that could explain why these properties are causing these issues or what I could do to fix them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Are you linking `CoreGraphics.framework` to your project?

Comment: No, I do not use CoreGraphics.framework in either my static framework or my Unit Test.

Comment: Yes you did. The two `CGColor...` functions are from CoreGraphics. You need to link the `CoreGraphics.framework` to your project. This will fix the linker error.

Comment: I am not sure why this was working before, but adding CoreGraphics.framework to both my StaticFramework target and the Unit Tests target fixed the trick. Could you submit the solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker error indicates that you are using CoreGraphics functions but you are not linking the CoreGraphics framework.

Update your project/target so you link the CoreGraphics.framework and the linker issues will be resolved.